# How do I optimise this SQL query for updating rows?

Tags: sql

I have two tables: one is a MasterList and one is a UpdatesList. I need to use the Updates list to make changes to certain columns in the Master List.

This is my query right now:

```
UPDATE Master
SET Region2Name=U.Region2Name 
FROM  Master M
    INNER JOIN Updates U
        ON M.PostalCode=U.PostalCode 
           and M.Country=U.Country
           and M.Lang=U.Lang
```

Is this the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: You could start by googling "sql update statement"

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do the following?

```
UPDATE M
SET  blah = meh
    ,...
FROM Master     M
JOIN Updates    U   ON M.PostalCode=U.PostalCode 
                    AND M.Country=U.Country 
                    AND M.Lang=U.Lang
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured that much out. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. If you find a better way, I think we'd all love to know about it.

Comment: On second thought, you could use a MERGE statement - but you'd need to test which is faster, I do not know offhand.